# Feed RSS not updating for W3 validator

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss, feed

I have a problem with my feed rss actually.

I did many tests, and i have to modify my feed rss view (customize it).

Here it's my feed rss : [http://agro-media.fr/?feed=email](http://www.agro-media.fr/?feed=email)

When you are in the link, you see there is no apparent problems.

However, when you check this link in W3 validator or if you choose this feed in mailchimp, he says "THIS IS NOT A VALID RSS FEED, because there is on the top of the feed this :

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

BUT NO WAY. I deleted it before...

I already did many things like : 
- clear WP Rocket cache
- clear Varnish cache
- clear chrome cache
- Server reboot

I don't have more ideas, maybe you can help me ...

thanks a lot guys, have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server software seems to act differently when different user-agent header is present. I tried `curl`ing your feed URL and got something in binary-like format. When I modified my user-agent like so:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5" www.agro-media.fr/?feed=email
```

I got a correct response that starts like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="0.92">
<channel>
    <title>Agro Media</title>
```

Unfortunately, I can't help you further, although I've found the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Dmitry Kurilsky, but i found the problem :

App like feedvalidator or w3c feed validator have cache, and they're updated after a while.

Plus : I merged my feed with mailchimp, and the update between the both is very intense --> I have to wait few hours until the change (synchronization) on the feed make effect.

Sorry for my english tho.